# How do I force eclipse to update the apk on my hardware device with each build?

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx

If I change some code, save, and Run, it runs the last version of the program, not what I just saved. The only way I can make it update is if I Clean the project, Build the project, and then Run the project. Is there some way to avoid this tedium?

Comment: that's weird. Eclipse updates the APK inside bin folder of your project.

Comment: In the project menu has the "Build Automatically" been checked??

Comment: I have tried with auto build on and off, same problem.

Comment: Try running without saving. It will say there are changed files and prompt you to save them. Say yes and continue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm afraid that did not help, either.

Comment: could you tell me what you have in following setting: project->properties->Builder ?

Comment: @SudarNimalan: I am not sure this is what you are asking, but: there's text that says "Configure the builders for this project", and under it is a single option, "Java builder", which is selected (checked).

Comment: for android project, there should be, "Android Resource Manager", "Android Pre Compiler", "Java Builder", "Android Package Builder" in this order, chould you add those and try?

Comment: @SudarNimalan: I owe you an apology; I do have those four components. My "project" is split into 4 projects - "core", "core-android", "core-desktop", and "core-html". It's a little weird because I set it up with the libGDX project setup UI, and I was looking at the 'core' project when I answered your question. My 'core-android' project has all four (in that order), and it is the one that has the problem in my question.

Comment: could you please confirm the order of those builders, the changes you meant in the question also inside the android project right?

Comment: Yes, that order is what I have; I don't follow your second question?

Comment: you mentioned "if I change some code" it is inside android project right? not in other project say "core"

Comment: Ah, that *is* in core, yes. To be clear, if I make a change in core and rerun my android project, it does not update on my device. It's suddenly not mysterious why it was not updating - thanks. Is there a way to force it to update?

Comment: some more things to help understanding issue more, Could you change eclipse->window->Preferences->Android->Build->Build Output to "Verbose" and check when you do changes in "core" and save you should observe "Starting incremental Package build: Checking resource changes. Skipping over Post Compiler." inside console output. for this you should have added "core project" to "android project"->properties->Java Build Path->Project.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13497/discussion-between-shino-and-sudar-nimalan)

Comment: On Eclipse, go to Window-Prefences->run/debug ->launching 

And then, on Save required dirty editors before launching : 
choose the Prompt option,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I spent some time create two dummy projects (one Android and one Java) and have a play with it, and finally come up with a workaround which is not used very often but able to solve your requirements.

First, I will explain your question a bit more (based on my understanding and what I have tried) so that other people can have a more clear understand about what is happened here.

According to the conversation in comments:

> could you tell me what you have in following setting: project->properties->Builder ? – Sudar Nimalan
>
> @SudarNimalan: I am not sure this is what you are asking, but: there's text that says "Configure the builders for this project", and under it is a single option, "Java builder", which is selected (checked). – shino
>
> for android project, there should be, "Android Resource Manager", "Android Pre Compiler", "Java Builder", "Android Package Builder" in this order, chould you add those and try? – Sudar Nimalan
>
> @SudarNimalan: I owe you an apology; I do have those four components. My "project" is split into 4 projects - "core", "core-android", "core-desktop", and "core-html". It's a little weird because I set it up with the libGDX project setup UI, and I was looking at the 'core' project when I answered your question. My 'core-android' project has all four (in that order), and it is the one that has the problem in my question. – shino

#### Scenario:

You have 4 project:

- core: a regular java project (common pure java code here)
- core-android: an Android application project.
- core-desktop: not related to question so ignored.
- core-html: not related to question so ignored.

The core-android project has dependency on core project, by adding core to core-android's build path (Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects -> Add ...) and export list (Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export).

#### Problem (Not Really):

Change some code in core and save it, run core-android, eclipse install last compiled apk, not the new one with change.

#### Reason:

<strike>The is the expected behavior, the way you used to reference core project in core-android only create a weak link (or something sort of) between core and core-android, the core-andorid's auto-build script doesn't aware any changes made in core. You have to clean the project (only need clean core-android project) so that Eclipse can delete the existing apk (under bin directory) and re-generate the apk (with the latest code changes from core).</strike>

#### See Xav's comments below, Android SDK tools should aware changes from plain Java project under project build  path, and it does not behaviour this feature normally at the moment.

Note that if core is an Android Library project, then there is no problem and your core-android project will aware any changes in core project (java code, android resource and etc), if core is only used in core-android, this could also be a workaround: turn Java project core into Android library project.

#### Workaround (Eclipse Link Source):

There is another way (not commonly used) for adding soft link between projects:

1. First, you need remove core project from core-android's build path, this will also remove it from Export and Order list.
2. Right click core-android, choose Build Path -> Link Source ... Add ../core/src as Linked Folder Location and src-lib1 as Folder Name,see screen screen in the end.

This create a symbolic link src-lib1 under core-android in Package Explorer windows point to core's src foder, in the file system, you still have two separate project folder. Now if you change some code in core and run core-android, Eclipse will build and install latest apk. No need to clean core-android project.

Link Source Window:
[image]

Final look in Package Explorer:

[image]

You should always consider the normal approach as first option, after all, manual clean project is not a big deal compare to the unusual approach I described above.

Comment: @shino, glad to hear it helps.

Comment: This is really not how it should work. Referencing a project from another one means that the main project (android in this case) gets notified (rather its builders) of changes in referenced projects. There might be a problem in our builders when that notification happens though, but it should work out of the box.

Comment: @Xav, Thanks for your comments, perhaps we should raise a bug in [Android Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/advsearch). Anyway, good to see some guru from Android team participate in StackOverflow:)

Answer (score 4):

Please follow this steps..

**1.** `Project--> Build Automatically been checked??`

**2.** `Please following setting: project->properties->Builder` like that?

**Check below image.**

[image]

And Also Check Below Settings.

[image]

Also Check Below Image

[image]

IF problem continues then please Update your `ADT` & `SDK`.

Hope it works for you .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please read the comments under my question, things are more complicated than I realized and the nature of my situation is more evident now.

Comment: @shino Can you please upload your project->properties->Builder images ?

Comment: @shino Also project->properties->java build path Images so more idea where is your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Navigate to *Windows->Preferences->Android->Build*. Make sure that the checkbox "Skip packaging and dexing..." is NOT checked.

Comment: No luck, still. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

The Problem is the In your Eclipse, go to `Project Properties - Builder`, There is one CheckBox with `AndroidPackageBuilder` that is *required to be Checked True*. Now everytime you will do any changes in you project that will be reflected in your build and the Compiler will never say that 
 "Application Already Deployed, No need to Reinstall"

This will work evenif you dont have selected Build Automatically, Because everytime you run by clicking Run icon or Ctrl+F11 that will first Build the Project and Then Run it. So The requirement is just to **Enable the Android Package Builder**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please read the comments under my question, things are more complicated than I realized and the nature of my situation is more evident now.

Comment: I have read those, I have tried the above with a project where there are total 4 packages, I changed in mainactivity then run the project "without enabling the Android Package Builder" and it said me "Application Already Deployed, No need to Reinstall"...then I checked that..enabling the APB the new updated apk got installed...

Comment: Tell me like, You have enabled the APB and still its not taking the new APK each time?

Comment: Thanks for your response. To be clear, I have four separate projects, not packages (I'm not sure if this is what you mean). I have all four of the items checked in my Builders list, but it still does not update my device.

Comment: You mean that There is one Main Android project and other 3 projects are library project added in the main project..?

Answer (score 0):

You won't believe how easy and silly is the solution

On Eclipse,
go to Window-Prefences->run/debug ->launching 

And then, on Save required dirty editors before launching :

choose the Prompt option,

Apply and OK