# Android build in Eclipse not picking up changes to linked Project

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changes in code aren't reflected when I run Libgdx project on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160191/changes-in-code-arent-reflected-when-i-run-libgdx-project-on-android)

I've been developing an Android application in Eclipse for several months.  Recently, I've been running into a problem where I make a change to my source then hit Ctrl+F11 to run the application on a physical device, but my recent changes are not reflected.  As far as I can tell my code is being compiled, but its not being repackaged into the APK.

I'm using libGDX, so my Android app actually consists of two projects, the Android one, and a platform-independent bit (and the libGDX libraries).  The Android project includes the common one as a "Project" (in the Java Build Path preferences).

When I make a change to some of the non-Android-specific common code, I believe the Android project's builder is "seeing" the change, as the "Console" log shows (since I enabled Verbose builds in `Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Build: Build Output` settings):

```
[2012-07-23 13:42:04 - Project - Android] Starting incremental Package build: Checking resource changes.
[2012-07-23 13:42:04 - Project - Android] Skipping over Post Compiler.
```

("Project - Android" is the name of the Android-specific parts of the project.)

If I try to run the Android build after the changes are made, I get the "you didn't make any changes" warning (so it just brings the existing instance forward on the device instead of killing it and launching new code):

```
[2012-07-23 13:46:44 - Project - Android] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
```

If I explicitly clean the build (`Project -> Clean`), any changes I've made get incorporated and the resulting Android project deploys with those changes.  So, I believe the basic paths and build infrastructure is working correctly, its just that something isn't right with the incremental updates.  Note I have `Project -> Build Automatically` checked.

If I build a "desktop" version (like the Android version, but a third project that includes the common code), incremental builds after a change to the common code work.  So, it seems like the problem is in the Android-specific parts of the build system (maybe?).

Are there any logs I can look at to get more details about how the build system is deciding what needs to be rebuilt or not?

I'm using Eclipse Indigo:

```
 Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

 Version: Indigo Service Release 2
 Build id: 20120216-1857
```

I'm using the latest Android SDK (SDK tools rev 20, and compiling against SDK 16).

### Update

Other libGDX users have narrowed this down to SDK v20: http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=4627&hilit=build+project+linked

And thanks to the folks on the libGDX forum, there is a bug filed at google: <strike>http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34305</strike> (dup'd against:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36174)

Comment: I sure hope someone has the answer to this because I have been seeing it a lot too.

Comment: Enable the verbose build output in the preferences under Android > Build. Also, do you have auto-refresh enabled?

Comment: @Xav I've got verbose builds enabled already.  I quoted the two relevant lines, I think, but if there is more detail you'd like to see let me know.  I do have `Project -> Build Automatically` checked, too (assuming that's what you jean by "auto-refresh builds"?)

Comment: See if my post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304516/how-do-i-force-eclipse-to-update-the-apk-on-my-hardware-device-with-each-build) answer your question. In short, this is the expected behaviour.

Comment: @yorkw Interesting ... its odd that this is "expected" behavior, as I'm pretty sure its new behavior.  I'm pretty confident Eclipse used to do the "right thing" without any special effort, but maybe I'm mistaken.  Plus, I'm pretty sure the android project *is* aware of the changes in the platform independent bit (the verbose Android compiler spits out a couple lines when I make a change and save the files), so I believe the Eclipse Project linking is doing the right thing.  That said, your proposed work-around might fix my problem, so I'll probably give that a try later.  Thanks!

Comment: Regarding to the "new behaviour", you probably mean [this](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects), however, it doesn't mention whether changes from Java-only project are automatically detected by Android build process.