# Changes in code aren't reflected when I run Libgdx project on Android

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx

I've been following the Libgdx tutorial [here](http://obviam.net/index.php/getting-started-in-android-game-development-with-libgdx-create-a-working-prototype-in-a-day-tutorial-part-1/) and I'm running into a strange problem. Due to the constraints of my work environment, I can't download OpenGL drivers on my desktop, so I can't test my application on the desktop. I have to test it on my Android device. It's running some variation of an Android 2.3.4 build, which is API level 10.

The problem is, whenever I make changes to my code and run the Android application, the changes aren't reflected. It just starts the build it installed the first time I ran my code. I uninstalled the app on my Android and re-ran it, running into the same problem. I made an entirely fresh Libgdx project and copied my new code over to it, and it worked fine, until I made more changes to the new version, then I ran into the same problem. So I know for a fact that the code I'm changing is making a difference in how it should look, it just isn't being reflected. Is there something I'm missing?

My steps, to clarify:

1. Set up a Libgdx project with gdx-setup-ui.jar
2. Import the newly created project to Eclipse using the default import settings
3. Code for a while, creating some version of my application (for instance, in that tutorial, I code till I set up the debug `ShapeRenderer`, and test to make sure my app looks right)
4. Run the Libgdx Android application to test it on my phone
5. Code some more, changing things, adding things, whatever (even changing images in my assets)
6. Re-run the Libgdx Android application to test it on my phone

   - The application that shows up is the same as it was when I ran it the first time in step 4

Comment: Have you tried running a clean in eclipse between code changes.

Comment: @Emile Well, I thought I did. Just tried that again and it worked. That's pretty annoying. Is there a fix for this, or is that just the way it is?

Comment: Not sure to be honest. I know that sometimes libraries won't be refreshed/updated and a clean is the only way to go. Have you got "build automatically" selected?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a bug in the newer versions of ADT. Please star the [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36174&thanks=36174&ts=1344514616) to make Google aware of the troubles this gives.

Easiest way is to `clean project` in Eclipse (or whatever IDE you are using) or to add a space/newline in your Android project and save.