# ShapeRenderer not rendering in NetBeans Android emulator

Tags: android, libgdx

I am working on a small project in Android and an testing the progress using Android plug-ins for NetBeans 7.0. The problem is that I am using ShapeRenderer to draw filled circle. When I am running in android emulator, I am not able to see the filed circle. But when I run the same application as desktop, I can see the filled circle.

```
 private void drawFilledCircle(){
   shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
   shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.FilledCircle);
   shapeRenderer.setColor(new Color(0, 1, 0, 1));
   shapeRenderer.filledCircle(470, 45, 10);
   shapeRenderer.end();
}
```

Anybody has faced this before or let me know if I miss anything? The framework I use is LibGDX and Android version is 2.3.3

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

I am able to see the output in now in android emulator as well. It looks it was not compiling the application properly. Thanks

Comment: Depending on which ADT version you're using, you may be running into this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160191/changes-in-code-arent-reflected-when-i-run-libgdx-project-on-android.  Upgrading to the most recent ADT should fix this, though.

Comment: @P.T. You could be right. I thought to do so at last. But however, I was able to see the change in the emulator. Thanks for that.