# Eclipse debugging sticks with dated app

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, libgdx

Whenever I debug application on hardware device, It runs with an old copy.

I tried :

- Restarting Eclipse
- Fixing Project with Android Tools
- Checking manifest file
- Unplugging the cable

Only thing that helps is cleaning the project.

Did I missed something ?

Comment: Try to uninstall the old app from your device.

Comment: Have you checked build automatically?

Comment: Uninstalling doesn't work. Build Automatically is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the latest ADT with "library projects", such that changes to indirectly dependent libraries do not cause the Android project to be rebuilt.  See [Android build in Eclipse not picking up changes to linked Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620745/android-build-in-eclipse-not-picking-up-changes-to-linked-project)

The work-around is to make any single change in the Android portion of your application (vs. just making changes in the common portion which won't trigger a rebuild).

Please "star" the bugs at Google about this:

- http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34305
- http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36174

Answer (score 0):

Try running the app rather than debugging it. If Eclipse thinks that the version on the device is current, you will get a message to that effect on the console. That will not fix your problem by itself, but it should give you some additional information to work with. The message does not appear when you debug the app.