# Android project does not rebuild after modifying underlying Java project

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have an Android project (A) that depends upon a Java-only project (B) in Eclipse. To be specific, in the Project properties of (A), Java Build Path->Projects, (B) is listed as a required project on the build path.

When I edit source files in (B) and then save, then run the Android project, I get the following warning in the Console:

```
ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

The root problem seems to be that the .apk file is not getting rebuilt.  E.g. it was last modified at November 8, 2012 1:46:41 PM, then I made a change in B and saved.  The timestamp remains the same.

To work around the problem, I can modify a file in (A). Interestingly, after saving, the .apk is still not updated!  (I have "Build automatically" enabled).  But when I run the Android project, it forces the .apk to be rebuilt and then my changes to (B) get propagated to the .apk file.

I believe this used to work with an earlier version of ADT, but I'm not sure when it stopped working.  I'm currently using Eclipse 4.2.1 (Juno) with Android Development Toolkit Version: 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395

Is there something possibly missing in my project setup?  Or is this an ADT bug?

Comment: Try deleting the `gen` file and then building your project

Comment: Do you mean that as a workaround or to solve the overall problem?

Comment: This might be an ADT bug, see my answer and Xav's comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304516/how-do-i-force-eclipse-to-update-the-apk-on-my-hardware-device-with-each-build/11361278#11361278).

Comment: AFAIK this is how things have worked for the last 2 years.  I got used to going to the root android project, modifying a file, saving and then running to get the apk updated.

Comment: @Error454, like I said in the question, it used to work.  I put down this Android project for about 6 months and I'm sure it used to work correctly back then.  When I restarted the project 3 weeks ago, I upgraded to Eclipse Juno (from Indigo) and picked up the latest Android tools.  Anyway, looks like a recent bug... there seem to be at least two other questions on StackOverflow with the same problem (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620745/android-build-in-eclipse-not-picking-up-changes-to-linked-project)

Comment: Wow, there's a bug filed against this and 300 people have starred it! http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36174  I don't know how I missed it when I filed this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in the r21 version of the Android SDK tools.