# Running my new code runs my old code?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

Somehow, whatever code I add to my program it does not run on my android device. It just runs my old code.

- I am constantly deleting my app from my phone in the App Manager.
- If I add new or change functionality the old code still runs.
- I even delete complete blocks of code that should obliterate functionality. But somehow all the old functionality remains in the app after reinstall.

Simple example: On a TextButton click i shift some UI element by 200. This works great. When i delete the complete button listener it still works great but i guess completely by itself since the code should be gone.

- I tried restarting Eclipse without luck.

This thing is driving me crazy. I was stuck for hours on some simple code and baffled why it did not run. Then I discovered my logs where not showing in logcat. Somehow, sometimes it does update the new code into the device since now i have a log on device resume but i deleted that at least 30 minutes ago and now it is still showing in my logcat.

Desktop app works as it should. I somehow have the feeling this happened before and over time this got worse, up to this point where i cannot test anything anymore.

So to be clear:

- I add code to my app.
- Run it from eclipse as Android application
- No changes show up
- Delete app from phone using the phones Application Manager
- Delete a complete code block like the `show()` method that holds my complete stage
- Run it from eclipse as Android application
- App still runs as it was with the complete stage in tact.

-- edit --

Now I did not do anything to my code for a while and ran it. Now it probably took the code with the version with the empty show() method. However this already has been undone in the present. Could eclipse be stacking runs?

Comment: Maybe is time to switch to Android Studio...

Comment: @BoldijarPaul Seriously? I finally got comfortable with eclipse, took me an age to get everything right. Does Android Studio supports LibGDX with desktop project?

Comment: Are you sure you are saving your file before compiling it? I know it is a stupid question, but I've had a similiar problem - turned out that eclipse was still using old file, not saving new before compiling it.

Comment: @MikołajMularczyk My project is autosaving, just tested that. But I'm hitting Ctrl-s more often then Clint Eastwood his trigger.

Comment: @MennoGouw yes it does, and way much better for gradle integration. I was using Eclipse like 2-3 months ago... I would never go back to it...Android Studio is the best in my opinion, for a pc / laptop with over 4GB ram.

Comment: @BoldijarPaul How does the android emulator work on Android Studio? It is slow as hell on AVD. Does it use the same? I was missing the functionality to test out my app on different devices. Anyway i definitely going to try it out. However i would die for a answer to this strange phenomenon.

Comment: @BoldijarPaul Wow already got my project going in Android Studio, downloaded it like 15 minutes ago. But I cannot seem to get my desktop project going. Is this really possible? Any good and new sources to set this up?

Comment: @BoldijarPaul Nevermind that last question, got everything up and running. This stuff worked like a charm unlike the Eclipse hell. Can't wait to code in this new IDE, hope it does more wonders.

Comment: try all the [answers in this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304516/how-do-i-force-eclipse-to-update-the-apk-on-my-hardware-device-with-each-build)

Comment: @MennoGouw Check up CTRL SHIFT N (to fast search a file) , CTRL ALT O (to remove unused imports) and CTRL ALT L (to indent your code )

Comment: It took you an age to get everything right because it was Eclipse. I switched to Android Studio a couple months ago after using Eclipse for years and it has been a total breeze to use. Just took me a few hours to get comfortable with Gradle. Also, Gradle flavors make packaging for distribution way easier.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Indeed it was as simple as it can get. Everything went automatic i just had to change the work path for the desktop app to function properly. Have to dive a bit more into gradle, i just use the libgdx setup to arrange the complete gradle project for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check

> "Project -> Build Automatically"

is checked. (Most likely your problem).

Also doing a

> "Project -> Clean..."

tells the IDE to delete any previously compiled binaries and rebuilds them. (The APK file).

Answer (score 2):

This could happen if there is an error in your code and you have selected run without warning when error in program exists. In such a case the last successfully built code would get pushed! As Lestat mentioned try doing a clean, if the project now shows up errors you have your culprit, else make sure your XML files are all proper.

Another check could be to see the timestamp of the last generated apk file in your workspace.

PS: There is a bug in eclipse where it doesnt save a file at time, a simple workspace restart fixes this.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue - updated my code and yet the phone was running the old.

1. Tried Build --> Clean Project
2. Tried File --> Invalidate Caches/Restart
   Now it works and recognizes the new code!

That said curious what #1 and #2 did behind the scenes??